BuildConfig does not get updated - invalid cache
I have a variable called OPT_OUT in my local.properties file which can be added and removed based on which add-ons should be visible - it is for local testing.
Let's say that i don't have this OPT_OUT field defined in my local.properties file - I build it, it is initialized to null, great.
Now I add it (OPT_OUT = GLOBAL_SEARCH), build it and even though it looks like it changed, for some reason it does not and returns the previous null value

As you can see I hover my cursor above the BuildConfig.OPT_OUT variable and it shows its value is "GLOBAL_SEARCH" but temp1 is initialized to null
agp = "8.4.2"
kotlin = "2.0.0"

